# HidD_GetPhysicalDescriptor on a HID device with Citrix enviroment GetLastError 87

Tags: windows, hid, citrix

Same code and device work fine when direct connection (HID <-> Host), but fail as title description when in Citrix enviroment through usb redirection.

```
if(!HidD_GetPhysicalDescriptor(hDev, pu8DataBuf, 4096)){
    printf("HidD_GetPhysicalDescriptor error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

What could be reason?